# Boxing value type decimal to nullable object?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I unboxed two nullable `object` (*i.e. `object?`*) to `decimal` and performed some arithmetic on the operands returning a result...
(Throwing exceptions if not possible)

How do I box the result back to `object?`?

Edit:
Code as requested in comment below.

```
        var baseValue = scope.GetByPath(localPath); //object?
        var rhsValue = Rhs.Execute(scopeIterations); //object?


        decimal res;
        if (baseValue is decimal)
        {
            if (rhsValue is decimal)
            {
                switch (Operator)
                {
                    case ArithmeticOperator.Add:
                        res = ConvertToDecimal(baseValue) + ConvertToDecimal(rhsValue);
                        object? foo = res;
                        break;
                }
            }
```

So I am getting IDE complaints when boxing `res` to `object?` obviously.

This is from a lib:

```
    private static decimal ConvertToDecimal(object? value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is string valueAsString)
            {
                return Convert.ToDecimal(valueAsString, (Some CultureInfo);
            }

            return Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }
```

Comment: Please, share your code. Are you using nullable reference types from C#8?

Comment: `object boxedObject = myDecimal;`

Comment: Wouldn't just object? o = value; work?

Comment: Don't down vote w/o argument. This is a issue I was assigned for a repo, language and VM (.NET CORE) which I have never worked with before.

Comment: @tortal In this case make sense to spend some time reading [boxing and unboxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) basics. If you get any specific error with your code, please share it with others here. `object? foo = res;` works just fine, if you've enabled nullable reference types in project file or via code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks. No it is not C#8. 
I guess the design I am forced to work with here just boggled my and my IDE's mind.

Comment: @tortal `object?` is definitely C# 8 declaration, in earlier version you'll get something _feature nullable reference types isn't available, please use language version 8.0_

Comment: Well your example is exactly the same as doing `object? o = 4M;` right? If yes, this is working perfectly well

Comment: @Bidou correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you would like to do that, there might be better ways.

anyways, you can always cast. Check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B7Nr2V)

```
    int theInt = 8;
    object theObject = theInt;
    int? nullableInt = theInt;

    Console.WriteLine($"{theInt} - {theObject} - {nullableInt}");
```

Comment: yeah, i am pretty confused by the design choices here. Just doing what the issue ticket described. Gonna try this. Rider is complaining tho, might compile anyway - let's see...

Comment: @tortal, there are times where you need to do what you describe, for example if you are using extenal libraries that force you, so I will not judge :)  I think the code i put does what you describe, but if you are not sure if there are better ways, you can put some context and we will try to help :)